# Log all program external call

Tags: executable, logging, debugging

When I execute a third-party program, is it possible to see (and keep track) all the possible external calls to other programs, with corresponding parameters?

Suppose I have a program "foo" which, at some points, calls different external scripts or shell commands. Is it possible to keep track of those?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for `strace` -  comes from strace package.

for example you can track down file related syscalls  by running:
`strace -e file ls`

alternatively one can use `LD_DEBUG` environment variable.
It is not well known, but still quite interesting way of debugging, especially useful if you can't install strace or other debugging tools.

`LD_DEBUG=help cat` will give you the options.